# Number of specific digits in a number

Tags: c, digit

```
#include <stdio.h>

int elofordul(int sz, int szj) {
    int count = 0;
    while (sz > 0) {
        int szj2 = szj % 10;
        sz = sz / 10;
        if (szj2 == szj)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int szam, szj;
    scanf("%d", &szam);
    scanf("%d", &szj);
    printf("%d", elofordul(szam, szj));
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. It just prints the all the digits.
`sz`: number, `szj`: digit

Comment: Shouldn't that be `szj2 = sz % 10`? (It's not very clear from the variable names, but I think you want to count how often the digit `szj` occurs in `sz`. Please try to choose unique variable names, Hungarian or otherwise. White space also helps to make the code more readable.)

Comment: What is the Input and the expected Output?

Comment: @MOehm that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your function: `szj2 = szj % 10` should be `szj2 = sz % 10`.

You should use English names for variable and function names, and comment in English too.  Your variable names are confusing and indeed confusion struck.

There is another potential bug in your version: the program should probably print `1` for input `0 0`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_digit(int number, int digit) {
    int count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (number % 10 == digit)
            count++;
        number /= 10;
        if (number == 0)
            return count;
    }
}   

int main() {
    int number, digit;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    scanf("%d", &digit);
    printf("%d", count_digit(number, digit));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should he feel obligated to comment in English?

Comment: @nicomp: for interoperability with programmers around the globe, and especially on stackoverflow.  I am not an English native either, but I enforce this rule for my own teams.  On a lesser note, C keywords are English words, mixing them with local language words feels awkward.

Comment: You probably meant `if ((number /= 10) == 0)`. Maybe you can write the loop as `do { ... } while ( number /= 10 );` if it's not too obscure.

Comment: @Bob__: good catch!  I updated the code to make it less obscure.  I only use `do {} while` loops in macros with a `while(0)` condition.  From my experience, `do / while` loops are error prone because programmers tend to omit important conditions.